# Register dynamically Connected App: was anybody successfully done it?

Tags: connected-apps, dynamic, dynamic-binding

Register dynamically Connected App: was anybody successfully done it?

I tried to follow the steps provided in this article

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oidc_dynamic_client_reg_flow.htm&type=5

I created a Connected App, generated Initial Token and tried to make Post request to both `https://myorg.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/register` and `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/register` like described in the article

```
POST /services/oauth2/register HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <initial.access.token>
Host: myorg.salesforce.com

{"redirect_uris":["https://client.salesforce.com/redirect.html",
"https://client.salesforce.com/callback","http://localhost"],
"response_types":["code","token","id_token"],
"grant_types":["authorization_code","implicit","refresh_token"],
"application_type":"web",
"contacts":["abc@sf.com","ve7jtb@example.org"],
"client_name","Client Name Example",
"logo_uri":"https://client.salesforce.com/logo.png",
"client_uri":"https://client.salesforce.com/info.html"}
```

but both failed with `500` status code and `Server Error` status and neither one returned `200` to me.

Did I miss something or is this some raw alpha feature which is not completely functional right now?

Is this not allowed to call from Apex itself?

Comment: Is this a timing issue? Do you need to wait some time before you can successfully invoke the oauth2 APIs against the Connected App?

Comment: I don't think so, but let me try again today

Comment: Tried again and received Gack Id 429499227-23954 (374666145). I gues I will open a Salesforce Support Case for this

Comment: @Patlatus Based on the stacktrace Id 374666145 that you provided, I see the details as `com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected : at line 1 column 321 path $.client_name` in our salesforce logs.I will update this thread as I have more details. Thanks

Comment: I think today I will have a call with SF Support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in the example from documentation there was some small misprint which I didn't notice, instead of part of the request body

```
"client_name","Client Name Example",
```

I should have sent

```
"client_name":"Client Name Example",
```

and now it is working!

This is example of successfully working the code

```
@SuppressWarnings('PMD.ApexSuggestUsingNamedCred')
public static HttpResponse register(String email, String name) {
    HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
    String inx = 'Replace by your initial access token';
    hr.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + inx);
    hr.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    hr.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json'); 
    hr.setHeader('Host', getHost()); 
    hr.setTimeout(120000);
    hr.setBody(
        '{"redirect_uris":["' + getBaseURL() + '/callback",' +
        '"' + getBaseURL() + '/sandbox"],' +
        '"response_types":["code","token","id_token"],' +
        '"grant_types":["authorization_code","implicit","refresh_token"],' +
        '"application_type":"web",' +
        '"contacts":["' + email + '"],' +
        '"client_name":"' + name + '",' +
        '"logo_uri":"",' +
        '"client_uri":"' + getBaseURL() + '"}'
    ); 
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ Host: ' + getHost() );    
    hr.setEndpoint(   getBaseURL() + '/services/oauth2/register');   
    //hr.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/register');   
    hr.setMethod('POST');
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ hr: ' + hr );         
    HttpResponse r = new Http().send(hr);            
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ r.getStatus(): ' + r.getStatus() );           
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ r.getStatusCode(): ' + r.getStatusCode() );           
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ r.getBody(): ' + r.getBody() );           
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ r.getHeaderKeys(): ' + r.getHeaderKeys() );           
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ r.setCookie(): ' + r.getHeader('Set-Cookie') );
    if (r.getStatusCode() == 201) {
        //MetadataApi.deployment();
    }
    return r; 
}

public static String getBaseURL() {
    return Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm().replace('http:', 'https:');
}
```